# ASP.Net MVC Custom Authorization for Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a complex application with lots of Web Api Calls which need permission checks that are within the database.  An example simple api call I might have is:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<StudentContact> GetStudentContacts(int id)
    {
        return db.StudentContacts.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.StudentId == id && n.Current_Record == true).OrderBy(n => n.RankOrder);
    }
```

And to do a permissions check I have to do the following:

```
int staffID = (User as CustomPrincipal).UserId;
int siteId = Functions.GetSiteIdFromCookie();
if (Functions.UserHasAccess(staffID, AccessLevels.access_StudentDetailsUpdate,siteId) == true) return true;
else return false;
```

What I would like to achieve is to create a custom authorization annotation so that I can have:

```
[HttpGet]
[PermissionAuth(AccessLevels.access_StudentDetailsUpdate,AccessLevels.access_StudentDetailsReadOnly)]
public IEnumerable......
```

And I may need to have an option of and/or i.e. both are true or one is true.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at using a filter?

Comment: No is it easy to setup a custom filter? Will it deny access to the function?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by extending the `AuthorizeAttribute` and overriding the `IsAuthorized` method.
Something like the following is what you need.

```
public class PermissionAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly List<string> _accessLevels;


    public PermissionAuth(params string[] accessLevels)
    {
         _accessLevels = accessLevels.ToList();
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
        {
            return false;
        }
        int staffID = (User as CustomPrincipal).UserId;
        int siteId = Functions.GetSiteIdFromCookie();
        if (Functions.UserHasAccess(staffID, AccessLevels.access_StudentDetailsUpdate,siteId) == true) { 
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false
        };
    }
}
```

Then above your method use `[PermissionAuth(/*permissions here*/)]`

Comment: I'll have a crack at this.  What do you suggest I do in the case of an OR? i.e. as long as one of two permissions were set.

Comment: essentially you just have to adust the logic if the `IsAuthorized` method returns true they are allowed in

Comment: In the code above how do I get the permissions entered in the annotation into the IsAuthorized method?

Comment: They will be in the `_accessLevels` variables

Comment: VStudio doesn't like the _accessLevels = feature line here as it does not exist in the context

Comment: sorry i just fixed that